# Не открывает вложение reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Есть главная App.js

Сделала открытие

```
<Link to={`/show/`}><button class="btn">Мои заказы</button></Link>
```

Подключила в index.js

```
 import Show from './components/Show';
<Route  exact path='/show/' component={Show} />
```

При yarn start все работает
Если выгрузить на хост, то не переходит на другие вложения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том что Ваш хостинг не сконфигурирован для размещения на нём [SPA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Нужно настроить сервер таким образом чтобы вне зависимости от URL все пути вели к *index.html*.

Пример конфигурации файла *.htaccess*:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [QSA,L]
</ifModule>
```